# Counting the occurrence of chars in a javascript string

Tags: javascript, string

I have written down code to calculate the count of each of the character in a string.
It seems to be working correctly for some of the words where as for some it fails.

It fails for the last character, as I see the length of the string becomes smaller than the iteration count (but for some of the words)

```js
var str1 = "america"

function noofchars(str1) {
  for (var m = 0; m < str1.length + 1; m++) {
    var countno = 1;
    if (m != 0) {
      str1 = str1.slice(1)
    }

    str2 = str1.substr(0, 1)

    for (var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
      if (str2 === str1.charAt(i + 1)) {
        countno += 1
        str1 = str1.slice(0, i + 1) + str1.slice(i + 2) + " "
      }
    }
    console.log(str1.charAt(0) + "=" + countno)
  }
}

var findnoofchar = noofchars(str1)
```

It passes for london, philadelphia, sears, happy
But fails for america, chicago etc
london = l=1, o=2, n=2, d=1

Comment: What exactly are you trying to find? A simple `.length` gives you exactly that.

Comment: Woudn't it have been simpler to use `str.length`?

Comment: @jhpratt The OP is attempting to count the occurrences of specific characters, not the whole length of the string.  e.g.: 'hello' would be h=1, e=1, l=2, o=1.

Comment: You are making your job much harder than it needs to be. It's almost never a good idea to loop over something and modify it at the same time. The standard way to do this is with an object where you set the object keys to each letter and increase the value each time you see the letter again. There should be lots of example threads here.

Comment: @Enthu Downvotes are a signal that your question is not of sufficient quality. You should be _very_ surprised that your question has three upvotes to only one downvote. Your original question was extremely unclear — we don't need to wait for your response to downvote, we downvote the question as it then stood.

Comment: @jhpratt I agree with that but I had edited it within 1 min to be honest, but yeah if down voting satisfies you , I am happy and I do not want to bother any one, thanks

Comment: @Enthu Downvoting isn't about satisfaction, it's about signalling the OP that they need to fix their question.  The downvote tooltip is "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"

Comment: Your _minimal_ clarification came four minutes after posting. I retracted my downvote after that time. I'm just responding to the fact that you believe I should've waited for your response (edit) before downvoting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It'd be easier to use an object. First `reduce` into character counts, then iterate through the key/value pairs and `console.log`:

```js
function noofchars(str1) {
  let r = [...str1].reduce((a, c) => (a[c] = (a[c] || 0) + 1, a), {});
  Object.entries(r).forEach(([k, v]) => console.log(`${k}=${v}`));
}
noofchars("america");
```

ES5 syntax:

```js
function noofchars(str1) {
  var r = str1.split("").reduce(function(a, c) {
    a[c] = (a[c] || 0) + 1;
    return a;
  }, {});
  Object.keys(r).forEach(function(k) {
    console.log(k + "=" + r[k]);
  });
}
noofchars("america");
```

It's easier to understand what `reduce` is doing in the above snippet.

First, we take a function with two parameters `a` and `c`. These can be called anything, I just use `a` and `c` for the **a**ccumulator and the **c**urrent item.

Now, the second line:

```
a[c] = (a[c] || 0) + 1;
```

This is kind hard, so let's break it down. First let's look at what's in the parentheses:

```
a[c] || 0
```

This checks if `a` has a key/value pair with the key `c` (as in, the *value* of `c`, not the *key* literally being `c`). If that doesn't exist, it returns `0`. So if `a[c]` exists, save it as the value of the expression, otherwise use `0`.

Now, we add `1`, to increment the value.

Finally, we assign the result to `a[c]`. So if `a` contained `c`, the value of `a[c]` would be incremented. If `a` didn't contain `c`, the value of `a[c]` would be `1`.

Then, we return `a` to be used in the next iteration of `reduce`.

In the next line:

```
}, {});
```

We assign a default value for `a`. If we didn't do this, the first time `reduce` ran, `a` would be `"a"`, and `c` would be `"m"` (the first two characters of `america`). This way, `a` is `{}` (an empty object), and `c` is `"a"`. If we didn't have this second argument, our function wouldn't work.

In this line:

```
Object.keys(r).forEach(function(k) {...});
```

We're getting an array of all the keys in `r`, and looping through them with `forEach`, with `k` being the key.

Then, we're logging `k` (the key), then an equals sign `=`, then the *value* of `r[k]`.

Comment: Could you please explain what reduce is doing here(as my understanding is reduce adds the result to the cumulative) it would be really helpfull, thanks

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation , I think I will have to revisit reduce function as I am not able to understand how they a[c] key/value pair is working , have seen reduce function in mdn but till date I do not understand, having said that I'll accept the answer and try to wrap my head around, it would be great if you can point to any good resource from which I can get a better understanding of Reduce

Comment: Glad I could help @Enthu. Here's one that I found useful: https://codeburst.io/learn-understand-javascripts-reduce-function-b2b0406efbdc.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string by each character and then count the number of occurrence of each character by `reduce` function as below

```js
function noofchars(str1) {
  const chArray = str1.split('');
  return chArray.reduce(function(acc, ch) {
    if (acc[ch]) {
      acc[ch]++;
    } else {
      acc[ch] = 1;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
 }

 var str1 = "america";
 var findnoofchar = noofchars(str1);
 console.log(findnoofchar);
```

In your solution you are mutating `str1` in this line

```
str1 = str1.slice(0, i + 1) + str1.slice(i + 2) + " "
```

which actually changes the length of the string and also checking `str1.length` in the first loop. In you case you can take the length in the first place. Working version of your code snippet is here

```js
var str1 = "america"

function noofchars(str1) {
  const len = str1.length;
  for (var m = 0; m < len; m++) {
    var countno = 1;
    if (m !== 0) {
      str1 = str1.slice(1)
    }
    if (str1.charAt(0) === ' ') {
      break;
    }
    str2 = str1.substr(0, 1)

    for (var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
      if (str2 === str1.charAt(i + 1)) {
        countno += 1
        str1 = str1.slice(0, i + 1) + str1.slice(i + 2) + " "
      }
    }
    console.log(str1.charAt(0) + "=" + countno)
  }
}

var findnoofchar = noofchars(str1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really knowing what you are trying to accomplish with your code, one solution is to utilize the charAt and Set functions. CharAt is a more direct way to iterate over the string and the Set function eliminates duplicate characters from the set automatically.

```js
var str1 = "america";
    
      function noofchars(str1) {
        var charList = new Set();
        for (var m = 0; m < str1.length; m++) {
          
          var charX = str1.charAt(m).substr(0, 1);
          var countno = 1;
    
          for (var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
            if (str1.slice(0, i + 1) == charX) {
              countno++;
            }
            charList.add(charX + "=" + countno);
          }
        }
        // you may need to expand set on Chrome console
        console.log(charList);
        // a hack to display more easily display on your screen
        var listOnScreen = Array.from(charList);
        document.getElementById('displaySet').innerHTML=listOnScreen;
      }
    
      noofchars(str1);
```

```html
<div id="displaySet"></div>
```